# Route is working when referred but when I go to that provided link it will not find the controller function in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have added a custom function to save pictures and added the route as well and when I reference the route it does work but when visiting it gives error that the function can not be found with reflectionexception error ReflectionException

`Function () does not exist`

**Controller**

```
/**
*    show the form for uploading profile picture 
*    
*   @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
*/
public function changePicture()
{

    return view('usersinformation.profilepicture');
}
```

**route -- web.php**

```
Route::get('usersinformation/changePicture',[usersinformationController::class, 'changePicture'])->name('usersinformation.changePicture');
Route::post('usersinformation/savePicture', 'usersinformationController@savePicture');
```

Comment: can you please paste the full error message

Comment: you're not using a proper controller in `POST` route. try same way you did for `GET` --- `[usersinformationController::class, 'savePicture']`

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi using a string like that for a route is a correct syntax in all versions still

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi when I use the above as you said, it'll not give error during path resolution but it'll not find the path when a request is sent to the function.

Answer (score 0):

you should add this line to above of web.php file.

> use App\Http\Controllers\usersinformationController;

(if your controller is in default path)
but if your controller path is different you should modify and add your path to the code.

Comment: the controller is in the default path

Comment: then add this code above of web.php file.
use App\Http\Controllers\usersinformationController;
then test it.

Comment: I have already found the answer for this and updated it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the issue resolved by adding below route.

```
Route::get('usersinformation/saveePicture', [
'as' => 'usersinformation.savePicture',
'uses' => 'usersinformationController@savePicture'
```

]);